# Backbone PUT request to cross domain is not appending id to URL

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following backbone model.

```
var aModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   url: 'http://api.site1.com/list
});

modelObj = new aModel();
```

Domain of my application is `product.site1.com`, so all the request made to server by my application are cross domain requests.

All my backbone requests to the API needs common header, so I have written following backbone sync method

```
var sync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    options.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('key1', 'ABCD');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('key2', 'EFGH');
    };
    sync(method, model, options);
};
```

When I execute fetch method like below

```
modelObj.fetch();
```

My application makes a OPTIONS request to the `api.site1.com/list`

On success of that request it makes a GET request to `api.site1.com/list`

This is the same case for POST as well.

When I perform 
`modelObj.save({name: "abc"})` before fetch, my app sends OPTIONS request to `api.site1.com/list`,  on success it performs POST request.

Whereas when I do it for update i.e PUT,

I expect backbone appends id to the url, like `api.site1.com/list/1` and performs OPTIONS request

But when I check my dev tools, the OPTIONS request is made to `api.site1.com/list`. On success, it makes PUT request to `api.site1.com/list` instead of `api.site1.com/list/1`

Why is this happening and how to handle this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting `aModel.url`, you force the url used in the requests. Set [`aModel.urlRoot`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot) instead :

> **urlRoot** model.urlRoot or model.urlRoot()
>   Specify a urlRoot if you're
>   using a model outside of a collection, to enable the default url
>   function to generate URLs based on the model id.

Try

```
var aModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   urlRoot: 'http://api.site1.com/list'
});
```